# After instaling window 8 Brightness control not working

Tags: window

After installing new Windows8 ultimate OS.
Brightness control keys are not working of my laptop.
My laptop model is TOSHIBA SATELLITE C660D

I search for drivers but not find suitable and working driver for my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue and have solved it like this 
Just right click --> My Device/Mycomputer  ---> Manage --->Device Manager

Then find Monitor open **Monitor** section 
And then right click on **Generic PnP Monitor** and click enable

Then you will be able to use brightness keys in window 10 and 8

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with Lenovo Y570. The software for managing fan speed does not wortking properly - it does not manage fan speed. Try to install soft which manages brighetness for windows 7 and compatibility mode.

P.S. Don't forget to create `Restore point` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rollback driver to Windows default driver.

goto Control Panel - Device Manager - Display Devices - Right Click on Intel Graphics - Click on RollBack - Confirm - Ok.